# Selecting tables with one record in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select table_name, 
to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select 
count(*) c from '||owner||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count 
from all_tables
```

I would like to get those with one record in the table.

Comment: Your result set doesn't include the owner. Would USER_TABLES rather than ALL_TABLES still satisfy your requirement?

Comment: I replace the owner with actual owner. It works but not the outer select with count = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query crashes only when the filter predicate is applied. It's probably a bug in some query rewrite optimization. If you wrap the query in a block with the `materialize` hint, it seems to bypass this behavior.

```
with workaround as(
    select /*+ materialize */ 
           owner
          ,table_name
          ,to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ' where rownum <= 2')),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as row_count 
      from all_tables
     where owner = '<your-schema>'
)
select owner, table_name, row_count
  from workaround
 where row_count = 1;
```

I also found some potential to improve the performance of this query. If you only want tables with exactly one record, there is really no need to count every single record in the table. If you add the predicate `rownum <= 2` Oracle will stop scanning as soon as it has found two records. So the count will be either:

- 0, meaning empty table
- 1, meaning exactly one record
- 2, meaning more than 1 record

Edit to show how the optimization work:

```
-- Creating tables 
create table t0(c number);
create table t1(c number);
create table t2(c number);
create table t3(c number);

insert into t1 values(1);


insert into t2 values(1);
insert into t2 values(2);


insert into t3 values(1);
insert into t3 values(2);
insert into t3 values(3);

commit;
```

SQL:

```
/*
|| Without rownum you can filter on any rowcount you want
*/
select *
  from (select 'T0' as t, count(*) as row_count from t0 union all
        select 'T1' as t, count(*) as row_count from t1 union all
        select 'T2' as t, count(*) as row_count from t2 union all
        select 'T3' as t, count(*) as row_count from t3
       )
  where row_count = 1 -- Return tables having exactly 1 record.
  ;

/*
|| With rownum <= 1 Oracle will stop counting after it found one row.
|| So the rowcount will be either 0 or 1.
||  row_count = 0 means that the table is empty
||  row_count = 1 means that the table is NOT empty.
||
|| The Rownum predicate prevents us from knowing if there are 2,3,4 or 5 million records.
*/
select *
  from (select 'T0' as t, count(*) as row_count from t0 where rownum <= 1 union all
        select 'T1' as t, count(*) as row_count from t1 where rownum <= 1 union all
        select 'T2' as t, count(*) as row_count from t2 where rownum <= 1 union all
        select 'T3' as t, count(*) as row_count from t3 where rownum <= 1 
       )
  where row_count = 1 -- Return tables having at least one record
;  


/*
|| With rownum <= 2 Oracle will stop counting after it found two rows.
|| So the rowcount will be either 0, 1 or 2.
||  row_count = 0 means that the table is empty
||  row_count = 1 means that the table has exactly 1 record
||  row_count = 2 means that the table has more than 1 record
|| 
|| The Rownum predicate prevents us from knowing if there are exactly two records, or 3,4,5 etcetera
*/
select *
  from (select 'T0' as t, count(*) as row_count from t0 where rownum <= 2 union all
        select 'T1' as t, count(*) as row_count from t1 where rownum <= 2 union all
        select 'T2' as t, count(*) as row_count from t2 where rownum <= 2 union all
        select 'T3' as t, count(*) as row_count from t3 where rownum <= 2 
       )
  where row_count = 1 -- Return tables having exactly one record
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks. But i noticed that some of the tables do contain more than 1 record. Do i need to run some statistic check within oracle to update the xml? i am not running the latest version - 11g

Comment: you misunderstood the count. Your query counts all records in the table, then you filter by count = 1. My query returns the first 2 records of all tables and counts them. If the count is 1, then there is only one record. If the count is 2 then we don't know how many records the table contains, only that it contains more than 1, thus not satisfying your requirement.

Comment: oh rownum..  i update rownum = 1, it still give me table with more than 1 record

Comment: Mich, did you even execute the query? Please read what I wrote carefully. I'm not giving you ideas for how to change the query. I'm giving you the query you must execute. It works exactly as it stands - or not at all.

Comment: Given the condition of rownum <= 1. the count(*) will always be 1 or 0 if empty. Thus result will show a list of tables matching the condition - at least 1 record and not only 1 record. Am i right to say?

Comment: with rownum <= 1 you can deduct two things: Table is empty or table contains at least one record.
with rownum <= 2 you can deduct three things: Table is empty or table contains exactly 1 record or table contains more than 1 record.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge sharing

Answer (score 1):

If your query is giving the data you want, but you just want to see the results with `count` equal to 1, you can wrap the query like this:

```
select * from (
  select table_name, 
  to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select 
  count(*) c from '||owner||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count 
  from all_tables
) where count = 1
```

Comment: i have the error occured when processing the XML function when i added the count = 1

Comment: @Mich - maybe we could guess what error you've got but why not make everybody's life easier and just tell us?

Comment: i got this error when i added the outer select and where condition. The original query works fine

ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 176
ORA-06512: at line 1
19202. 00000 -  "Error occurred in XML processing%s"
*Cause:    An error occurred when processing the XML function
*Action:   Check the given error message and fix the appropriate problem

Comment: I get the same error message in version 12.1.0.2.0, I think it's a bug

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT table_name, 
  TO_NUMBER(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||OWNER||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) AS cnt 
  FROM all_tables
  ) 
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT table_name, 
  TO_NUMBER(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||OWNER||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) AS cnt 
  FROM all_tables
  ) slct
GROUP BY slct.table_name
HAVING slct.cnt = 1;
```

Comment: For either of these to work you need to use the correct column alias in the subquery. Because you have left it `as count` both of these will hurl `ORA-00904:` because `cnt` is an invalid identifier.